# Skip the steps after certain condition

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

Is there any way to skip the steps after certain condition and get the scenario result passed.

My scenario is this: check for a certain product if that product is not visible skip the remaining steps and result should be passed

Comment: you should ideally have 2 scenarios to test. One where product is visible other not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skip certain steps in a scenario in Cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721556/skip-certain-steps-in-a-scenario-in-cucumber)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Royg,

But found the answer - we can use Assume.True(condition) - to halt the execution and remaining steps will be skipped with scenario status passed
But in the cucumber report, this scenario will not be shown as JSON was not created yet

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721556/skip-certain-steps-in-a-scenario-in-cucumber). The answer is in Ruby and not in Java, but the condition is the same. You can also use this example if [this](https://makandracards.com/makandra/27057-cucumber-skipping-steps-in-a-scenario-outline-based-on-the-current-example) is your use case.